# How to use CMYK colors in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, cmyk

I am using Inkscape 0.91. I have created an artwork using Inkscape and converted it into PDF. While taking print copy I could not get the exact color used. How to make it CMYK mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Inkscape does not support CMYK out of the box. You're better off using Scribus if you want to output in CMYK. You can import your .pdf or .svg file into Scribus and export as .pdf, then under the "**Color**" tab, in "**Output Intended For:**" select the option "**Printer**." Scribus is open source and you can get it at scribus.net.

Here's an example of CMYK .pdf generated by Scribus on Ubuntu: http://goo.gl/mflcA4

You can learn more about **Color Management** in Scribus [here](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Color_Management_setup).

Comment: The fact that I want to specify my colors in a CMYK color space rather an RGB color space does not mean that I also want to perform color management by attaching a color profile with the document. In fact, I may specifically want to *not* attach a color profile, so that I retain control over the inks rather than the actual perceived color. How does Scribus help me here?

Comment: @Witiko Scribus helps OP output in CMYK, which exactly what he asked for. You don't have to attach a color profile while exporting as .pdf in Scribus, at all.